# Loading .svg files in img tag with nextjs9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

Working on Migration project from Nextjs7 to Nextjs9, And could not able to include the .svg files in the image tag.

DEMO :
https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-mh9fp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Since it is a exiting project. I want to make the .svg files to work with img tag itself.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import Head from "next/head";
import RawData from "./static/raw_data.txt";
import SVGFile from "./static/SVGFile.svg";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>Trying out next.js</title>
    </Head>
    <div style={{ background: "green" }}>
      <img src={RawData} />
    </div>

    <div style={{ background: "red" }}>
      <h3>SVG IMAGES Included in img tag NOT LOADING</h3>
      <img src={SVGFile} />{/*Here is the problem*/}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: It is not the answer but the following code works https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-287p3 (it is just to give you something to debug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next.js is not support image import by default, you will need to use [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader).

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        outputPath: 'images',
      },
    });
    return config;
  }
};
```

Comment: I have made the changes you have posted here in : https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-ynkv6 . But this do not seems to be helping, can you please have a look and suggest me if you get any clue

Comment: The code sandbox is not using next.js (but regular client side React) & not using image loading from js.

Comment: thanks buddy, Is it ok, if you can demo me, import component kinda code, i.e., 'with import:' How to make this also work?

Comment: I've updated my sandbox, https://codesandbox.io/s/helloworld-c5b8u

Comment: I have question, can you have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542343/can-we-use-v9-1-7-canary-11-in-production-app

Comment: sorry to add it as comment, facing some issue:

I am facing the momory issues when I increased the version of my nextjs App from 7.0.0 to 9.1.4. since I wanted to adapt AMP (accelarated mobile pages). I wanted to increase the version. In my local system, as works well and app is faster also, but when deployed in production(AWS instances + Load balancer), may be because of Load there is a Memory Leak in the application.
please help @felixmosh

Comment: here is my package.json file 
https://gist.github.com/ravi-mone/f6f0314ff976af3cda9f5bde8b8330be

Comment: any help is great

Comment: Can you please have a look into the above messages @felixmosh